# Compute the MSE of this set of points (X, Y) with respect to the given regression model

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I am new to Machine learning . I am trying to find out MSE for given regression model linear regression line (model): y=7.93+1.12x. The data values for X and Y are (23, 41), (34, 45), (45, 49), (56,67), (67, 84), (78, 100).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That must be simple !!!
MSE means mean square loss error.
so assume your regression function is f(x) where x is the feature vector of dimension d.
the output of f(x) is scaler.
square error for one data sample(let it be x1,y1 ; x1 is a vector in d-dimensional space and y1 is scaler) is ( f(x1) - y )^2.

To calculate MSE, calculate the square error of each data point and then, add all square errors, divide the sum of square error by the number of data samples.

In your case, the dimension of the feature vector(x) is 1.
and f(x) =  7.93 + 1.12*x.

----CODE----

X = (23,34,45,56,67,78)

Y = (41,45,49,67,84,100)

SE = 0.0

for x,y in X,Y :

```
 SE = SE + ( 7.93 + 1.12*x - y)**2
```

MSE = SE/ len(X)

Comment: Can you please explain bit more . I am new to machine learning

Comment: len(x) means the liner model for x values or is the function of f(x)

Comment: len(x) means the total number of data samples you have. In your case, it is 6.  I think maybe your python concepts are not sharp enough. Try to refine them it would not take much time.

Comment: Thanks you for answering. How can you determine the initial values for SE is 0.0 ? To calculate the SE the liner model questions should be multiple * 2 not ** 2 ??

Comment: Actually, we are just accumulating loss for all data-samples.

Comment: SE must be zero because we are doing summation overall data samples. it is raised to power 2.

Comment: You can please suggest some python tutorial for this question. Yes you are right I am learning python as well

Comment: then please!!!, forget ML for a few days and focus solely on python and there is nothing like a tutorial for this question or that question. first, complete a basic python tutorial from this site https://www.w3schools.com/python/ , and then go to the Coursera course of Andrew ng on machine learning(you should be able to find it online easily). then go for tutorial in python dedicated to machine learning.   after it you can start real ML start reading Linear algebra,statistic,optimization ,probability and then books dedicated to ML(theoratical ones).you have to walk alot to be ML engg.